# Stop WordPress Entirely and Run My Own Code

Tags: multisite, init

I have a site that must be deployed in a WP Multisite environment but none of the code in the site uses WordPress at all. How can I intercept WordPress, perhaps at 'init', and tell it to stop doing anything and let me take over?

I tried just putting everything in my `index.php` file and include everything manually from there. However, this results in the `<head>` of my page being loaded within the body. So it's obvious that I need to interrupt WordPress before it can run `wp_head()`, but don't know how this might be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hook [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) and check the [current blog ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id)

```
function wpa85780_my_app_init(){
    $my_blog_id = 99;
    if( $my_blog_id == get_current_blog_id() ):
        include 'somefile';
        exit;
    endif;
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa85780_my_app_init' );
```

This will exit before WordPress does the main query and loads the template.

**EDIT**

a slightly earlier action you could hook is `after_setup_theme`, that seems to be the earliest that `get_current_blog_id` will work. See the [action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) page for the order of actions.

Comment: Thanks Milo - you were right that after_setup_theme was needed to intercept.